# my emulator crashes when i run it with a recycler view

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Just as the title says.

I dont think my adapter and view holder are wrong (but then again its my first time using it), but upon launching the programme, my emulator crashes. Is it something to do with my layout?

(I've attached screenshots of my layouts, my code for recycler view, and the logcat message)

[image: layout of recycler view]

[image: layout to inflate recycler view]

[image: Log Cat error message]

**ViewHolder**

```
public class myPageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

TextView rName, rDesc, rDuration, rIngredients, rSteps;

public myPageViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    rName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rName);
    rDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rDesc);
    rDuration = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rDuration);
    rIngredients = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rIngredients);
    rSteps = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rSteps);
}
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class myPageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myPageViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Recipe> data;

public myPageAdapter(ArrayList<Recipe> input) { data = input; }

public myPageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View item = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mypagelayout, parent, false);
    return new myPageViewHolder(item);
}

public void onBindViewHolder(myPageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Recipe r = data.get(position);
    holder.rName.setText(r.getName());
    holder.rDesc.setText(r.getDescription());
    holder.rDuration.setText(r.getDuration() + "mins");
    holder.rIngredients.setText(r.getIngredients()[('\n')]);
    holder.rSteps.setText(r.getSteps()[('\n')]);
}

public int getItemCount() { return data.size(); }
}

// Creates recyclerView to display recipes
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    myPageAdapter adapter = new myPageAdapter(recipeList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Create an ArrayList to store all the recipes
ArrayList<Recipe> recipeList = (ArrayList<Recipe>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("rList");

// Receives any intent
Intent intent = getIntent();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Finds icons
    ImageView create = findViewById(R.id.createImage);

    // Create onClickListeners for create
    create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent gotoCreate = new Intent(MainActivity.this, createRecipe.class);
            startActivity(gotoCreate);
        }
    });

    // Creates recyclerView to display recipes
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    myPageAdapter adapter = new myPageAdapter(recipeList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Comment: Please add photos of your `MainActivity.java` & `activity_main.xml` and the log when the app crashes

Comment: @AbdallahA.Odeh for the xml do you want to see the code instead of the design? And why the log as well?

Comment: for the xml, the design would be better to see all views ids, the log shows what the exception is about, I believe that it's and `ids` related issue

Comment: @AbdallahA.Odeh I edited my post, it has the code for MainActivity.java, and screenshots for activity_main.xml and logcat

Comment: Move `Intent intent = getIntent();` to be inside the `onCreate()` method

Comment: @AbdallahA.Odeh still crashes

Comment: did the log message change? if so update it please

Comment: also the initialization of the arraylist `ArrayList<Recipe> recipeList = (ArrayList<Recipe>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("rList");` must be inside the onCreate, because you can't use `getIntent` in the global scope of the activity, `ArrayList<Recipe> recipeList = new ArrayList();` ... and inside the onCreate: `recipeList .addAll(getIntent().getSerializableExtra("rList"));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245711/discussion-between-kelven-lim-and-abdallah-a-odeh).